# What does it mean that learning torah is greater then respecting parents

Tags: torah-study, shulchan-aruch, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

In the [shulchan aruch yora daiya 140.13](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.240.13) it says:

> תַּלְמוּד תּוֹרָה גָּדוֹל מִכְּבוֹד אָב וָאֵם.
>   Talmud Torah is greater then respecting the father and mother

What does this mean practically?
Is it only about the relative merits of mitsvois?
Or there is a practical law? If yes, what is the law?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One example is the ruling of the Terumat Hadeshen (40; cited [here](http://www.kby.org.il/english/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=3604)) that one can choose one's yeshiva over the objection of one's parents. Similarly, the Pri Chadash (cited in Pitchei Teshuva 240:8) infers from this rule that one can study far from his parents even though this will prevent his being available to honor them.

Answer (score 4):

The Gemara says the following in Megillah 16b:

> אמר רב יוסף: גדול תלמוד תורה יותר מהצלת נפשות. דמעיקרא חשיב ליה למרדכי בתר ארבעה ולבסוף בתר חמשה. מעיקרא כתיב אשר באו עם זרבבל ישוע נחמיה שריה רעליה מרדכי בלשן, ולבסוף כתיב הבאים עם זרבבל ישוע נחמיה עזריה רעמיה נחמני מרדכי בלשן. אמר רב ואיתימא רב שמואל בר מרתא: גדול תלמוד תורה יותר מבנין בית המקדש, שכל זמן שברוך בן נריה קיים - לא הניחו עזרא ועלה. אמר רבה אמר רב יצחק בר שמואל בר מרתא: גדול תלמוד תורה יותר מכבוד אב ואם, שכל אותן שנים שהיה יעקב אבינו בבית עבר לא נענש.

To summarize: Rav Yosef said: Torah study is greater than saving lives. Rav said, and some say this was said by Rav Shmuel bar Marta: Torah study is greater than the rebuilding of the Temple. Rav Yitzchak bar Shmuel bar Marta said: Torah study is greater than honoring one’s parents, for Jacob was not punished for his time spent studying Torah away from home.

We may ask what the Gemara is trying to teach us about Torah study and these other mitzvos. Is it telling us that if one can only perform one or the other that Torah study takes precedence? Or is it telling us which mitzvah is greater (reflected perhaps by greater reward for its performance)?

The Tur rules that one prioritizes saving lives over Torah study (YD: 251).

The Maharshal (cited in Bach there), however, disagrees with the Tur, understanding that one actually ought to choose Torah study over these other mitzvos (he is referring specifically to saving lives)!

> כתב מהרש"ל (בהגהותיו לטור) ע"ז ותימה הלא אסיקנא בסוף פ"ק דמגילה (טז ב) גדול תלמוד תורה יותר מהצלת נפשות

However, the Maharshal’s student; the Prisha (thereon: 13) argues with his mentor and defends the Tur, writing:

> ונלע"ד דהתם מיירי שיש אחרים שיכולים להציל הנפשות ולכן אף על פי שהוא מצוה גדולה מי שמקדים להציל נפשות מ"מ תלמוד תורה קודם הואיל שיש אחרים שיכולין להציל הנפשות

That is, Torah study only takes precedence if someone else will save the life. If there is no one available to save the life, however, then one must stop learning to save the life.

The Bach, too, disagrees with Maharshal, writing:

> ולא קשה מידי דהתם לא קאמר אלא דגדול הוא העוסק בתורה להחשיבו ולהקדימו יותר ממי שעוסק בהצלת נפשות דאינו חשוב כמו העוסק בתלמוד תורה אבל להוציא ממון להצלת נפשות פשיטא הוא דקודם להוצאה לתלמוד תורה דאין לך דבר שעומד בפני פיקוח נפש דוחי בהם ולא שימות בהם (יומא פה ב) ופשוט הוא:

That is, the Maharshal’s question is not difficult at all, since in saying that Torah study is greater than saving lives, the Gemara never intended to suggest that Toarh study supersedes saving lives; rather, that it has a greater relative merit. And it is obvious that one must save a life rather than study Torah. This is clear from the fact nothing takes precedence over saving lives, and he concludes that this is all obvious.

The Taz (to Shulchan Aruch there: 6) also disagrees with the Maharshal sharply, siding with the Tur, Prisha and Bach, and writes:

> ואין כאן קושיא דודאי אין לך דבר עומד בפני פיקוח נפש אלא דהתם אומר דיותר יש זכות למי שזוכה לעסוק בתורה ולא בא לידו הצלת נפשות ממי שבא לידו הצלת נפשות ועל ידי כך צריך לבטל תלמוד תורה ולעסוק בהצלת נפש... ויותר תימה על בעל הדרישה שכתב בתירוץ קושיא זאת דאם הוא בענין שאין יכול לקיים שניהם אז תלמוד תורה קודם כו' וזה ודאי אינו

He reiterates that the intent of the Gemara is not that Torah ought to supersede saving lives, but rather, that one is luckier if he merits to study Torah, than to save lives. He concludes that the Maharshal was certainly mistaken. Furthermore, the Taz compares the different mitzvos that the Gemara there lumps together as being inferior to Torah study.

The Ohr Hachayim, in Rishon Letziyon to that passage in Megillah, also disagrees with the Maharshal, and sides with the Tur. He writes:

> שם גדול ת"ת יותר מהצלת נפשות וכו' פירו' דוקא כה"ג שעומד בפרץ לבל יבוא הדבר לידי סכנת נפשות אבל להציל מן הים ומן המפולת דקיימי נפשות להציל אין לך דבר שקול כפיקוח נפשות גם מאי דקאמר גדול ת"ת מבנין בהמ"ק מיירי דלא מתבטל בנינו מחמתיה אבל זולת זה בנין בהמ"ק עדיף...אבל בזמן הצלתן של ישראל פשיטא דעדיף ועדיף מת"ת ולא מבעיא דרבים אלא אפי' הצלת נפש דיחיד עדיף מת"ת

That is, it is obvious that the intent of the Gemara was not that one should not save a life, rather that if one can do both that studying Torah has the greater merit. The Ohr Hachayim too lumps together the different mitzvos mentioned in that passage (he mentions construction of the Temple) and writes that it is obvious that if someone else will not build it that a person must cease learning to do so.

He emphasized this same point in Rishon Letziyon (to YD 251: 14) once again emphasizing that this is obvious:

> אבל לפיקוח נפש דהיינו אם רואה נפש הולכת לאיבוד פשיטא דמבטלין ת"ת עליה דאפילו שבת מחללין ביטול ת"ת דלא הוי אלא עשה מיבעיא ופשוט:

Rambam does not quote this Gemara in Megillah (AFAIK) which implies that it is not halachic. This would seems to align him with the Tur, et al. rather than the Maharshal. Indeed Rambam [(Hil. Talmud Torah 3:3)](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1303.htm)  states unequivocally that every mitzvah takes precedence over Torah study.

> היה לפניו עשיית מצוה ותלמוד תורה--אם אפשר למצוה להיעשות על ידי אחרים, לא יפסיק תלמודו; ואם לאו, יעשה המצוה ויחזור לתורתו

This is based on the Yerushalmi Pesachim (ch. 3).

See also Rabbi Yerocham Fischel Perlow (commentary to Rav Saadya Gaon's Sefer HaMitzvos (Assei: 9-10) who writes that at least some kibbud av v'em supersedes Torah study:

> מתחייב לבטל מת"ת ולעסוק במצות אביו ואמו משום עשה דמורא דעדיפא מת"ת

The Terumas Hadeshen (40) references the Gemara in Megillah in a halachic context, which is in accordance of the minority view of the Maharshal, and apparently against the Rambam, Tur, Bach, Perisha, and Taz's reading of the Gemara in Megillah.

---

Interestingly, a careful reading of Rashi's commentary (Genesis 28:9), (at least according to one text) suggests that Jacob shouldn’t have studied but rather served his parents. Nevertheless, the great merit of the Torah protected him from punishment for this misdeed.

> ובשביל זכות התורה לא נענש עליהם

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your work but I do not yet see a direct answer to my question

Comment: @hazoriz Try rereading it. Especially Reb Yerocham Fischel, and the Rambam And the Taz who equates the different mitzvos in Megillah 16b and the Ohr HaChayim who also equates the different mitzvos there. They both along with virtually all the other sources I cite agree that the gemara in Megillah is not saying that one should study Torah, rather than perform these other mitzvos, but rather that the mitzvah of Torah study is greater.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how to understand the shulchan aruch, it seems the shach and taz are saying like rashi (the way you explain), but the pischai teshuva (quoted in the other answer) seems to bring another point

Comment: @hazoriz I felt the answer was long enough as is. This is after all not the Encyclopedia Talmudis :) Are you referring to the Shulchan Aruch YD 240:25?

Comment: I know but the quality is similar :-), no i meant 240.13 (the one in the question)

Comment: Shach 15 , Taz 15, pischai techuva 8 http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6694

Comment: @hazoriz All the Taz does is quote the Gemara in Megillah which the Shulchan Aruch is quoting. This does not tell us whether he read it like the Tur, or the Maharshal. Indeed, we know from the Taz in siman 251 that he disagrees with the Maharshal. Same with the Shach. One could ask a seperate question on the Tur, Bach, etc. of how they understood the Gemara in Megillah, and how they understood Yaakov's conduct. I have some ideas, but it should be emphasized that this is a separate question, from what the intent of the Gemara is in its _maskana_ that Torah study is "greater".