# Where does Taz say I should feel bad if I cannot learn because Hashem gave me a different mitzvah?

Tags: torah-study, tzedakah-charity, shulchan-aruch

Where does Taz say I should feel bad if I cannot learn because Hashem gave me a different mitzvah that only I can do?
Meaning, that Hashem is not pleased with my Torah right now.
I think it is in Hilchos Tzedaka, but I cannot find it.

Comment: The Taz gives a proof from Mordechai

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67080/1739 https://parshaponders.com/tzav-5778/

Answer (score 2):

The Taz is in SA 251.14, Sayif Katan 6.

SA 251.14.

> The community authorities may use even school-funds if necessary, for the payment of the annual per-capita tax of thirty Peshitim1 to the commander of the city's troops, because it is a matter of life and death; for if they will not come to terms with him now, many poor people, not having the wherewithal to pay, will be beaten and stripped naked.

TAZ

> ויכום ויפשיטום כו'. רש"ל הקשה על זה ותימה הלא מסקינן סוף פ' קמא דמגילה גדולה תלמוד תורה יותר מהצלת נפשות עכ"ל. ואין כאן קושיא דודאי אין לך דבר עומד בפני פיקוח נפש אלא דהתם אומר **דיותר יש זכות למי שזוכה לעסוק בתורה ולא בא לידו הצלת נפשות ממי שבא לידו הצלת נפשות ועל ידי כך צריך לבטל תלמוד תורה ולעסוק בהצלת נפש ויליף לה ממרדכי בלשן שתחילה שלא בא לידו עסק של הצלת נפשות היה חשוב בעיני חכמים יותר ממה שאחר כך בא לידו המצוה של הצלת נפשות והוצרך לבטל תורה כדאי' שם שלא מנאו אותו חכמים כמו תחלה** וא"ל ממה דאיתא שם גדול תלמוד תורה מבנין בית המקדש שכל זמן שברוך קיים לא עלה עזרא לבנין בית המקדש דהתם עלה זרובבל לבנות בית המקדש ולא נתבטל בנין בית המקדש בשביל שלא עלה עזרא אלא שעזרא לא רצה להצטרף עמו כי תלמוד תורה גדול מזה ונמצא הוה זה ממש כההיא דלעיל ויותר תימה על בעל הדרישה שכתב בתירוץ קושיא זאת דאם הוא בענין שאין יכול לקיים שניהם אז תלמוד תורה קודם כו' וזה ודאי אינו: ‏

We learn this from Mordechai Balshan who was greater when he was not involved in saving lives then when he was, although he was obliged to do so, because he became less involved in learning Torah.